# Adding a on scroll effect using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousewheel

I have a project that I am working on and I am trying to achieve a certain effect and I was wondering if anyone here could help me.

**Here is where I'm at now:**

http://jsfiddle.net/RT9g5/1/

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<body>

    <div class="section blue" id="section1">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <div class="scroll">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section green" id="section2">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <div class="scroll">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section red" id="section3">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <div class="scroll">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**Here is my CSS:**

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.section {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #697bab;
}

.green {
    background-color: #6dab69;
}

.red {
    background-color: #ab6969;
}
```

**Here is my Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.scroll a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Now I like that I am able to click on links to bring me to the various sections, but what I am looking to do is to make it when I use my scroll wheel on my mouse it will bring me to the next section/previous section. That way the effect will be really nice and smooth.

Here is an example of the final sort of mouse wheel scrolling effect I am looking to achieve:

http://flatguitars.com/

Notice when you use the scroll wheel on the mouse it brings you down to the next section completely.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

## SOLUTION

http://jsfiddle.net/MQqYN/16/

It's using jquery.mousewheel.js - thanks DOM for the tip!

Comment: clicking one of the section links should bring you completely to another section - im looking to make the mouse scroll wheel do the same thing

Comment: groovy, working on it

Comment: actually this is fairly complex, may not get to it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HJ2cU/1/ here is an update though to make the boxes exactly 100% height (added the border-box to account for the section padding)

Comment: Use [`jquery mousewheel`](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) and, on `mousewheel`, change the section.

Comment: Dom - this sounds like it is what I am trying to do, how would I implement that? I have jquery mousewheel installed now, but I don't quite know how to write the javascript to change the section

Comment: Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/MQqYN/16/